# Exporting QTP 12 results into html throws the error "The stylesheet does not contain document element"

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

In order to generate a HTML report, I was trying to execute below is the code. The script throws an error at "xmlSource.transformNode(xmlXForm)". The error says "The stylesheet does not contain document element".

Kindly help.

```
Function ConvertToHTML(sResultPath)
    'sResultPath = "C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\TempResults\"
    sProductDir = "C:\Program Files\HP\QuickTest Professional\dat\"
    strOldText = "UTF-16"
    strNewText = "UTF-8"
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Set xmlSource = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
    Set xmlXForm = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")

    xmlSource.validateOnParse = True
    xmlXForm.validateOnParse = True
    xmlSource.async = False
    xmlXForm.async = False

    xmlSource.Load sResultPath & "Report\Results.xml"
    xmlXForm.Load sProductDir & "PShort.xsl" 'if you want more details, then you can use PDetails.xsl
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sHTMLPath = Replace(sResultPath & "Report\Results.xml", ".xml", ".html")
    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(sHTMLPath, ForWriting, True)
    file.write xmlSource.transformNode(xmlXForm)
    file.Close

    fso.CopyFile sProductDir & "PResults.css", sResultPath & "Report\"


    Set file = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set xmlXForm = Nothing
    Set xmlSource = Nothing

End Function

Call ConvertToHTML("H:\GB_Automation\Res1\")
```

Thanks
Bavya

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing typically indicates that the stylesheet is empty or nothing was loaded.  Double-check that the file path of your XSL file is accurate.  According to your code, you are trying to load the file from here:

```
C:\Program Files\HP\QuickTest Professional\dat\PShort.xsl
```

You stated that you are using "QTP 12", but the last version of QTP was v11.  Starting with v11.50, it was renamed as Unified Functional Testing.  Part of that rename means that the default installation folder is no longer under "QuickTest Professional".

I just checked my installation of UFT 12 on a 64-bit OS, and the path I have for the same file is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\dat\PShort.xsl
```

For 32-bit OS, it would be:

```
C:\Program Files\HP\Unified Functional Testing\dat\PShort.xsl
```